# Error in opening the hierarchical stage : Flash Player Error

Tags: datastage

Opening the Datastage hierarchical stage we have this error :

```
Flash Player Error. This application requires an Adobe Flash Player ActiveX control of version 10 or later. Get Flash
```

Time ago, we modified the mms.cfg and it was working.

```
AllowListRootMovieOnly=1
AllowListUrlPattern=xxx:xxx
EnableInsecureActiveXNavigateToURL=1
```

But it seems that now they deleted the flash software from windows and we have back again this Error.

Does someone have a brilliant idea to resolve this ?

Thank You -

Comment: Check out https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/hierarchical-data-stage-flash-player-end-support-dec-2020

Answer (score 3):

Flash no longer exists. It was withdrawn by Adobe.  Harman has created a replacement, which does work with the hierarchical data stage.